# Incorrect pattern message configuration on CombinedSignInSignUp step

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Entering a password on a `CombinedSignInSignUp` journey step using an invalid pattern defined for that field results in the following error message being displayed above the entry section of the form:

> Incorrect pattern for [Password]

Is there a way to configure this error message so it can be made more user friendly?

Comment: Can you add more details? Like what is the sample you referred? Any GitHub link?

Comment: when are you seeing this?  on sign-in or sign-up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [spottedmahn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185123/spottedmahn) for the information on language customisation. As I am using custom B2C policies I can't edit the language features through the Azure Portal.

I found that [this policy](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_base.xml) from the WingTipGames example shows how to achieve what I want.

I added a LocalizedResourceReference to my ContentDefinition as follows:

```
<ContentDefinition Id="api.combinedsignupsignin">
    <LoadUri>https://www.mywebsite.net/login</LoadUri>
    <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
    <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.1.0</DataUri>
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
      <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" Url="https://mywebsite.net" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.combinedsignupsignin.en" />
    </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
  </ContentDefinition>
```

I then added this the following Localization section within BuildingBlocks:

```
<Localization Enabled="true">
  <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
    <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
  </SupportedLanguages>
  <LocalizedResources Id="api.combinedsignupsignin.en">
    <LocalizedStrings>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfIncorrectPattern">Please enter a valid password</LocalizedString>
    </LocalizedStrings>
  </LocalizedResources>
</Localization>
```

This resulted with me getting the desired error message on screen:

"Please enter a valid password"

Answer (score 2):

Yes but that message can be used for multiple fields.

See this guide: [Azure Active Directory B2C: Using language customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization).

---

1. Download the current content:

   [image: download langauge customization content]
2. Edit the json and re-upload it:

   ```
   {
       "ElementType": "ErrorMessage",
       "ElementId": null,
       "StringId": "UserMessageIfIncorrectPattern",
       "Value": "Incorrect pattern for: {0}"
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the information. As I'm using custom policies I'm unable to download the JSON from the Portal but your answer pointed me in the right direction. Please see my answer for how I resolved this.